# PHP/Javascript Color cell based on certain data inside it

Tags: javascript, php, html-table

I was wondering if it was possible to color a cell based on certain data inside of it. Right now I generated a table with some data inside the cells concatenated as such:

```
| Person   | Info                             |
|----------|----------------------------------|
| Person A |  Available                       |
|          |   Age: 10                        |
|          |   Weight: 110                    |
|          |----------------------------------|
| Person B |  Unavailable                     |
|          |  Age: 15                         |
|          |  Weight: 150                     |
|          |----------------------------------|
| Person C |  Available                       |
|          |  Age: 30                         |
|          | Weight: 180                      |
```

Right now I had javascript code that would color it when the only value inside was Available or Unavailable

```
var table = document.getElementById('table');
var tbody = table.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0];
var cells = tbody.getElementsByTagName('td');
console.log(typeof cells[7].innerHTML);
for (var i=0, len=cells.length; i<len; i++){
    if (cells[i].innerHTML === "Available"){
        cells[i].style.backgroundColor = '#01CC00';
    }
    else if (cells[i].innerHTML === "Unavailable"){
        cells[i].style.backgroundColor = '#FF9800';
    }
}
```

I haven't been able to find if I can somehow change the color if the data contains Available or Unavailable?
The way those 3 pieces of data are being put to a cell is I am just concatenating them and sticking them in a cell.

Comment: can you add the HTML ?

Comment: You can add the background color as cell class in PHP before composing the string. Other than that you're looking for "javascript string contains x" on google. http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/

Answer (score 0):

Here's example code showing how to add a class to each cell based on the original data:

```php
$data = [
    [true, 10, 110],
    [false, 15, 150],
    [true, 30, 180]
];

foreach ($data as $key => $row) {
    // compose text part
    $av = ($row[0] ? "A" : "Una") . "vailable";
    // use it for the cell's class:
    $class = strtolower($av);
    $age = $row[1]; $weight = $row[2];
    // insert class
    $td = "<td class='$class'>$av<br>Age: $age<br>Weight: $weight</td>";
    $x = chr($key + 65);
    echo "<tr><td>Person $x</td>$td</tr>\n";
}
```

Here's the output and some basic CSS:

```css
td {
  padding: 0 10px;
}

td.available {
  background-color: #01CC00
}

td.unavailable {
  background-color: #FF9800
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Person A</td>
    <td class='available'>Available<br>Age: 10<br>Weight: 110</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Person B</td>
    <td class='unavailable'>Unavailable<br>Age: 15<br>Weight: 150</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Person C</td>
    <td class='available'>Available<br>Age: 30<br>Weight: 180</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```